# how to dynamically increment input control by JavaScript....?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used for loop to copy the table to n times. The code below works only in first table. How can i get to work in all tables?. I am a beginner.

```js
function copy() {
  var text1 = document.getElementById("Name1").value;
  document.getElementById("Name2").value = text1;
  var text2 = document.getElementById("Name3").value;
  document.getElementById("Name4").value = text2;
}
```

```html
<td rowspan="3" style="height:100px;">Name <input type="text" name="Emp name" placeholder="enter your name" id="Name1" /><br> ID <input type="id" name="Emp Id" placeholder="enter id" id="Name3"> </td>

<tr id="p001">
  <td colspan="10" style="border:1px solid #ffffff;height:150px;"><input type="button" value="Get data" onclick="copy();" /><label for="text"> Name : <input type="text" id="Name2"></label>
    <label for="text"> ID   : <input type="id" id="Name4"></label> </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you mean when you have two similar tables of your above code the function doesn't work? If yes, then it's because of the duplicate ID's. Keep the ID numbers on the inputs but pass the ID name to the function. I'll make a fiddle if you don't understand. Keep '1' pass in 'name'. Other tables will be 'nameA' or whatever.

Comment: thanks for the response buddy....bt i cant understand clearly....bcz am a beginner buddy.pls help me out with code

Comment: Done :). I'll explain more if you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

ID's should always be unique. When using duplicate ID's it will only work on the first one and ignore the rest. By pushing in the selector to the function you can reuse your function for multiple tables.

https://jsfiddle.net/m5aqdswe/

```
onclick="copy('Name');"

function copy(selector) {
    var text1 = document.getElementById(selector + "1").value;
    document.getElementById(selector + "2").value = text1;
    var text2 = document.getElementById(selector + "3").value;
    document.getElementById(selector + "4").value = text2;
}
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT TO HELP WITH YOUR FIDDLE MISTAKE**

After checking your code I can see that you haven't implemented my fix. You have an onclick on the button calling copy();. You're not passing in any arguments so your JS is static. So when you add another table you're creating duplicate ID's.

When searching for an ID document.getElementById("Name1") it will search through the DOM until it finds that first id="Name1" and then stop. That is why your second table never works.

To fix that we need to push in your ID name to the function so that the JS becomes dynamic. copy('Name') where "Name" is the first part of your ID. The numbers will still be used.

In the function you need to grab that arguments by passing it in to the function and calling it whatever you like. I chose 'selector' because it is most descriptive. onclick="copy(selector)"

No the function will replace all the 'selector' variables with the string you passed through, namely "Name" so document.getElementById(selector + "1") will actually be document.getElementById("Name1"). This way you can create as many clones as you like but remember to change the clone table ID's and pass in the correct argument to the onclick.

Here is your fixed fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/3shjhu98/2/

Please don't just copy, go see what I did. You'll need to fix your clone function to use dynamic arguments instead of static ones.

Comment: thanks, bro.Bt it doesnt wrk for my code.waiit a sec bro i ll update the complete code of mine.

Comment: @Bala_Poyyamoli you'll need to change your onclick and the function as per my fiddle.

Comment: Hmmmm...can you made a jsfiddle with your code then I'll correct it. My fiddle works perfectly so could just be a typo somewhere.

Comment: here s my js fiddle @Gezzasa

Comment: Sry to disturb you again and again.Bro even ur fiddle is also not working.

Comment: your updated code is also not runs that code in second Table.

Comment: The clone row won't work because I haven't updated it. Unfortunately I can't rewrite all your code for you but have given you a good starting point. The "Get data" button works fine and will work fine if you add extra tables with dynamic ID's. Please take some time to go through what I have answered so that you can finish your function. You won't ever learn if others code for you unfortunately.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3shjhu98/3/ .....i updatd that fiddle...Here clonerow comment wroks well.please solve this

Comment: I  can understand bro.bt am struggling with it for more than 2 days.

Comment: @Bala_Poyyamoli I completely understand :). The problem is there are a lot of issues in your code. For loop won't run cause you minus 1 from num. Your table has a two word ID where you should always only have one. The table you're cloning will keep the ID's it has instead of creating dynamic ones. I would suggest you create a new function that instead of cloning the table, creates a whole new one with dynamic ID's. I would really love to rewrite your code for you but I don't have hours to spare. Rewrite your clone function to be dynamic and read about troubleshooting js.

Comment: thank u bro for ur kindness towards me.I 'll try my best bro.If You have time pls rewrite my code otherwise no probs bro....once again thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```js
function check() {

    var rowCount = $('table.mytable tbody tr');

    for (var index = 0; index < rowCount.length; index++) {
        var tr = $('table.mytable tbody tr')[index];

        var td = $(tr).find('td');

        for (var j = 0; j < rowCount.length; j++) {

            copy('table.mytable tbody tr[data-index=' + index + '] td[data-index=' + j + ']');
            
        }
    }
}

function copy(selector) {
 
    var val_1 = $(selector).find('input:first').val();
   
    $(selector).find('input:last').val(val_1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <table class="mytable">
            <tbody>
                <tr data-index="0">
                    <td data-index="0">
                        <input type="text" onblur="check()" />
                        <input type="text" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Hi. try it...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3shjhu98/4/  here is my fiddle bro.kindly go through it or edit it

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to pass table selector like [ table.className ] etc. then you find input text box and get the value this and paste into another text box.

Like this.

```
///it mean you pass first table row of first table data.
copy('table.className tbody tr[data-index=1] td[data-index=1]');

function copy(selector) {
    var val_1 = $(selector).find('input#Name1').val();

    $(selector).find('input#Name2').val(val_1);
}
```

Comment: `need to pass table selector like` pass it where? pass it to what?

Comment: thanks for the response bro.Bt i  cant able to understand.

Comment: @Jaromanda X if you know about jquery and this question then you can't comment like that way. off course I am saying about table selector and pass into the function. code updated you can see

Comment: @neerajpathak - adding code to the answer makes your point clearer for the less knowledgable

Comment: bro are u there@neeraj pathak